# Eliminite duplicates and form a new array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is a purely related to merging of arrays

I Have an array as below(This is obtained after querying the database through mysql query):

```
Array

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9083
            [devicecount] => 3
            [device] => Android
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9083
            [devicecount] => 17
            [device] => computer
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
             [id]=> 9083
            [devicecount] => 1
            [device] => Iphone
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9083
            [devicecount] => 3
            [device] => mobile
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9085
            [devicecount] => 4
            [device] => Android
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9085
            [devicecount] => 4
            [device] => computer
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9090
            [devicecount] => 2
            [device] => computer
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9090
            [devicecount] => 2
            [device] => Iphone
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9092
            [devicecount] => 4
            [device] => Android
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9092
            [devicecount] => 3
            [device] => computer
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9092
            [devicecount] => 4
            [device] => Iphone
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9092
            [devicecount] => 1
            [device] => mobile
        )

)
```

In the above array, there are duplicate id indexes. I need to eliminate these duplicates and get a new array as below:

```
Array(

[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9083
            [Android]=>3
           [computer]=>17
            [iphone]=>1
          [mobile]=>3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9085
          [Android]=>4
           [computer]=>4
            [iphone]=>N/A
            [mobile]=>N/A

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9090
          [Android]=>N/A
           [computer]=>2
            [iphone]=>2
 [mobile]=>N/A
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9092
          [Android]=>4
           [computer]=>3
            [iphone]=>4
 [mobile]=>1
        )



)
```

In the new Array whichever index is not set, it must be N/A and the device values in the old array will become the keys in the new array.

Comment: What have you tried so far/what problem are you having? (The purpose of StackOverflow isn't simply to do your work for for you.)

Comment: And what have you tried so far? We're not just doing your work here.

Comment: Could you include the SQL query? Because this could be solved in that, no need for processing it in PHP afterwards.

Comment: May be you can use **prankletteid** values as array keys. If so the
code is simple 
    `$result = array();
    foreach($array as $item)
    {
      if(!isset($result[$item['prankletteid']]))
         $result[$item['prankletteid']] = array(); 
      $result['prankletteid'][$item['device']] = $item['devicecount'];
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$res    = array();          
foreach($Your_array as $vals){
    $res[$vals["prankletteid"]]['id'] = $vals["prankletteid"];
    $res[$vals["prankletteid"]][$vals["device"]]  = $vals["devicecount"];
    /*To check devices, if not add NA*/
    if(!array_key_exists("mobile",$res[$vals["prankletteid"]])){
       $res[$vals["prankletteid"]]["mobile"]  = "NA";
    }
    if(!array_key_exists("Android",$res[$vals["prankletteid"]])){
       $res[$vals["prankletteid"]]["Android"]  = "NA";
    }
    if(!array_key_exists("computer",$res[$vals["prankletteid"]])){
       $res[$vals["prankletteid"]]["computer"]  = "NA";
    }
    if(!array_key_exists("iphone",$res[$vals["prankletteid"]])){
       $res[$vals["prankletteid"]]["iphone"]  = "NA";
    }
}
$result  = array_values($res);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Comment: I think what he want is to group by `prankletteid` and also count how many `computer/iphone/Android` was per `pranakletteid`.

Comment: @piotrekkr : Yeah..I will edit the answer

Comment: Edited the answer please check it now

Comment: @PrasanthBendra Thanks for your answer.I was able to combine the arrays to a new array. If any index is missing i must insert N/A into the array. How can I accomplish this? PLs help.

Comment: @user2428553 : But why do you want to add NA for something which is missing ? It will be a unnecessary data. If you are using this array somewhere else you can check for array index and find whether particular device is there or not (use `array_key_exists` function)

Comment: @PrasanthBendra I want to add N/A because, I am sending this data to the view part to display, so I need to populate the entire complete array to the view part

Comment: @user2428553 : Will there be any other data other than Android, computer,iphone and mobile ?

Comment: @PrasanthBendra There is no other data  other than Android, computer,iphone and mobile

Comment: @user2428553 : Edited the answer please check it

Comment: @PrasanthBendra Thanks. Its working. One more enhancement can be possible? It must match strings like "Android" or "android" , "iphone","IPhone" or "iPhone"  when we specify the device in the array_key_exists function. can it be done? Can we use something like strripos function or any other? If yes, can u please help?

Comment: @PrasanthBendra Thanks. It will be fine as of now.

Comment: @user2428553 : The best option will be make all keys to same case. Change `$res[$vals["prankletteid"]][$vals["device"]]  = $vals["devicecount"];` to `$res[$vals["prankletteid"]][strtolower($vals["device"])]  = $vals["devicecount"];` So that all keys will be lower case and check for lowercase key index

Comment: @PrasanthBendra Your approach is fine. Will work for me

Comment: @user2428553 : Ok cool :)

Comment: @PrasanthBendra In the output array, indices must be uniformly ordered for all the elements of the array. Because while we access the elements the array in the for loop, we get a different data or unmatching data.  Which is the PHP function to accomplish this?